# Vimeo thumbnail larger than 640px

Tags: php, vimeo

I'm using code similar to this to add thumbnails of vimeo videos to a page.

```
    <?php

        if(defined('AT_PROXY'))  {
              $aContext = array(
                  'http' => array(
                      'proxy' => AT_PROXY,
                      'request_fulluri' => true,
                  ),
              );
              $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

              $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php', False, $cxContext);
         } else {
              $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php');
         }

        $main_video = 9700052;     

        $contents = file_get_contents('http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/'.$main_video.'.php');

        $array = @unserialize(trim($contents));
        $video_thumbnail = str_replace('http://', 'https://',$array[0]["thumbnail_large"]);
    ?>

     <div class="video_thumbnail text-center">

          <img src="<?php echo $video_thumbnail ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" />

          <div class="play js-play" data-vid="<?php echo $main_video; ?>">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play play-btn"></span>
          </div>

     </div>
```

I'm using Javascript to play the movie when the js-play button is clicked.

My problem is the size of the thumbnail, the large size is 640px but I would like it slightly larger.

Is it possible to get the vimeo thumbnail at a larger size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the biggest size Vimeo gives is 640px you can resize the image with CSS.

```
 <img src="<?php echo $video_thumbnail ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive video-thumbnail" />
```

CSS:

```
.video_thumbnail {
  width: 760px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To grab original thumbnail file you can just php explode the size from the url like this:

```
$imgid = (explode("https://vimeo.com/",$videoURL)); //Grab the video id from url

$hash = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$imgid[1].php"));

$hash = (explode("_640",$hash[0]['thumbnail_large'])); //remove size restriction

echo $hash[0]; //return original thumbnail url
```

This was used inside of WP and works great to get the URL to the original thumbnail uploaded to Vimeo. Then you can use CSS to resize the image and have it not be super pixelated

Answer (score 1):

The urls you have provided are the old, deprecated Simple API. The Simple API only supports thumbnails up to 640px.

The current API (https://developer.vimeo.com/api) supports thumbnail sizes for all available video resolutions. This includes 960x720 if the video is HD, and 1280x1024 if the video was upgraded to 1080p.